# Powershell script parameter as variable name

Tags: powershell

I'm quite new to Powershell scripting and I have hit a bump where I obviously don't know how to ask Google the right question.

I am writing a script to be called from a system that only allows me to add a single parameter to the command line, but I in fact need more values to execute the script.

My idea is to build a variable for each possible parameter, and then use the variable going forward (Simplified):

```
$name1= "value1","value2","value3"
$name2= "value4","value5","value6"
$name3= "value7","vlaue8","value9"

foreach ($value in $nameX) { }
```

and then call the script like: script.ps1 nameX

But how to convert the parameter into the name of the corresponding variable?

Or are there easier ways...?

Comment: You could put your values into JSON or XML or Base64 or any serialization format.

Comment: You can concatenate arrays and loop over all values in one loop like `foreach ($value in ($name1 + $name2 + $name3)) { <# call the script #> }` or am I reading the question wrong? If you mean to send 1 parameter that holds different values, you could also send the script one comma-delimited string and have the script split that into an array. `$name1= "value1,value2,value3"` etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  See `Get-Help About_Splatting`  Worth a mention.

Comment: @leeharvey1, [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) is a good technique to know about, but it only works from _inside_ PowerShell, which appears not to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve your problem with the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) cmdlet:

```
# The one and only argument passed: the name of a variable defined inside
# the script; e.g., 'name1'
$variableName = $args[0]

# Define the variables that the argument can refer to:
$name1= "value1","value2","value3"
$name2= "value4","value5","value6"
$name3= "value7","vlaue8","value9"

# Use Get-Variable to get a variable's value by name.
# (Error handling omitted for brevity.)
foreach ($value in (Get-Variable $variableName -ValueOnly)) { 
  # ...
}
```